# Asynchronous method with context dispose

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have the following code below:

```
public Task<Service> GetSomething()
{
    using (var myContext = new DbContext())
    {
        var returnObj = (from rp in myContext.Services1
                        join op in myContext.Services2 on rp .Id equals op.ServiceId into g
                        join ep in myContext.Services3 on rp .Id equals ep.ServiceId
                        from n in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where rp.Name == code
                        select rp).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return returnObj;
    }
}
```

Now this is working and I am encountering error:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

After reading, looks like `FirstOrDefaultAsync` is a deffered execution and I need to convert it to `list` first for it to be concrete.

How am I gonna convert the result of this query because I tried `.ToListAsync()` but it doesn't have any `FirstOrDefault` after it anymore.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Do you have lazy loading enabled? If you have made the changes suggested by @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev and still getting disposed exception then I can only think of lazy loading as the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, EF6 `Async` operation is called and its task is returned to original caller. Then, `DbContext` is immediatelly disposed without waiting for completion.
It is an incorrect usage of `async/await` functionality.

You need to await the result before disposing your context:

```
public async Task<YourEntity> GetYourEntity()
{
  using (var myContext = new DbContext())
  {
    var returnObj = (from rp in myContext.Services1
                     join op in myContext.Services2 on rp .Id equals op.ServiceId into g
                     join ep in myContext.Services3 on rp .Id equals ep.ServiceId
                     from n in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where rp.Name == code
                     select rp).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    //return returnObj; // returns Task, wrong!
    return await returnObj; // returns result, right!
  }
}
```

This way, it will wait for operation to complete and then dispose `myContext`.

Comment: Mark your method as async like so `public async Task<Service> GetSomething()`

Comment: With C# 8 came the `Using Declaration` this allows us to do: `using var myContext = new DbContext()` https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/csharp-8-0-using-declaration.aspx