# Entity Framework Core: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a ASP.Net Core 2.0 project using Entity Framework Core

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0"/>
```

And in one of my list methods I'm getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context
> before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not
> guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
```

This is my method:

```
    [HttpGet("{currentPage}/{pageSize}/")]
    [HttpGet("{currentPage}/{pageSize}/{search}")]
    public ListResponseVM<ClientVM> GetClients([FromRoute] int currentPage, int pageSize, string search)
    {
        var resp = new ListResponseVM<ClientVM>();
        var items = _context.Clients
            .Include(i => i.Contacts)
            .Include(i => i.Addresses)
            .Include("ClientObjectives.Objective")
            .Include(i => i.Urls)
            .Include(i => i.Users)
            .Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || p.CompanyName.Contains(search))
            .OrderBy(p => p.CompanyName)
            .ToPagedList(pageSize, currentPage);

        resp.NumberOfPages = items.TotalPage;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var client = _mapper.Map<ClientVM>(item);

            client.Addresses = new List<AddressVM>();
            foreach (var addr in item.Addresses)
            {
                var address = _mapper.Map<AddressVM>(addr);
                address.CountryCode = addr.CountryId;
                client.Addresses.Add(address);
            }

            client.Contacts = item.Contacts.Select(p => _mapper.Map<ContactVM>(p)).ToList();
            client.Urls = item.Urls.Select(p => _mapper.Map<ClientUrlVM>(p)).ToList();
            client.Objectives = item.Objectives.Select(p => _mapper.Map<ObjectiveVM>(p)).ToList();
            resp.Items.Add(client);
        }

        return resp;
    }
```

I'm a bit lost especially because it works when I run it locally, but when I deploy to my staging server (IIS 8.5) it gets me this error and it was working normally. The error started to appear after I increase the max length of one of my models. I also updated the max length of the corresponding View Model. And there are many other list methods that are very similar and they are working.

I had a Hangfire job running, but this job doesn't use the same entity. That's all I can think to be relevant. Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363807/a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-asynchronous-operat?rq=1).

Comment: @Berkay I saw that and many other similar questions and tried them. My method was async and I made it sync to avoid these issues. I also tries to remove the mapping, also tried to remove the .ToPagedList it continues throwing the error.

Comment: Having had the same problem I discovered I had nullable integers in my database table. as soon as I set my entity model properties to matching nullable int's, it all started working so, the messages were misleading for me...!

Comment: As often happens with such general exceptions, people start listing their own cases where the same exception occurs. Please, don't. It's irrelevant. What matters is that a context is used in multiple threads which is never a good idea. There can be hundreds of scenarios where this is the root cause of the exception.

Comment: Use `async Task<>` everywhere and don't forget to `await`.

Answer (score 218):

I am not sure if you are using IoC and Dependency Injection to resolve your DbContext where ever it might be used. If you do and you are using native IoC from .NET Core (or any other IoC-Container) and you are getting this error, make sure to register your DbContext as Transient. Do

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

OR

```
services.AddTransient<MyContext>();
```

instead of

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
```

AddDbContext adds the context as scoped, which might cause troubles when working with multiple threads.

Also [async / await operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363807/a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-asynchronous-operat?rq=1) can cause this behaviour, when using async lambda expressions.

Adding it as transient also has its downsides. You will not be able to make changes to some entity over multiple classes that are using the context because each class will get its own instance of your DbContext.

The simple explanation for that is, that the `DbContext` implementation is not thread-safe. You can read more about this [here](https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/#:%7E:text=DbContext%20is%20not%20thread%2Dsafe,over%20the%20same%20database%20connection.&text=Any%20instance%20members%20are%20not%20guaranteed%20to%20be%20thread%20safe.)

Comment: When I use transient i get following connection errors (closed or disposed) 'OmniService.DataAccess.Models.OmniServiceDbContext'.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. ...
Object name: 'AsyncDisposer'.

Comment: Hi @David! I guess you are using `Task.Run(async () => context.Set...)` without awaiting it or creating a scoped db context without awaiting the result. This means your context is probably already disposed when accessing it. If you are on Microsoft DI, you must create a dependency scope yourself within that `Task.Run`. Check out these links as well.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047877/asynchronous-method-with-context-dispose


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory.createscope?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: As pointed out earlier, if you miss to call an async method with the await keyword, you'll face this issue.

Comment: This helped me. I am injecting dependencies on a new thread from a hosted service when we receive a new message from a queue. Making my context transient fixed the exception

Comment: This is the one that helped me! My context is not static. I added ServiceLifetime.Tansient in my AddDbContext in Startup class and worked like a charm

Comment: @LetieTechera great! Yeah, is unlikely that people still do use statics but it happens.

Comment: If using a `TransactionScope` this can cause an exception "This platform does not support distributed transactions." in certain circumstances. E.g. if using multiple Mediatr requests within a transaction scope.

Comment: Would you mind elaborate a little more? I could add it to the answer.

Comment: Is it safe to use? I mean: setting ServiceLifetime to Transient will bypass this error creating multiple instances of DbContext, but what happens when multiple threads save data to database at the same time? Can this solution cause any problems?

Comment: @Piotrek as I mentioned that this will be one downside. You will not have shared context throughout a request lifetime so you cannot make changes to one entity over multiple classes, which you shouldn't anyway. I have used this approach in a rather back application (2million LoC) and haven't had any problems.

Comment: This can be fine, but one must be more thoughtful about the desired lifetime and resolution scope of data access than to cavalierly use transient without nuance of the circumstances. In fact, I'd consider it rare that one would want a data context transient. If the scope of a unit of work is something involving more than a single data operation, transaction scope should span more than that. Resolution of your data context should mirror the scope of your unit of work. This is something that should be thought through and this is not a one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: @alsami you are my hero. 6 hours of painful debugging. This was the solution. If someone else is injecting IHttpContextAccessor into the DbContext and the Claims are null, this is the solution. 
Thank you very much man.

Comment: If transient registration helps you're maybe using your Context the wrong way. Inform yourself about UnitOfWork pattern..

Comment: Unit of work and repository pattern is already implemented by entity-framework core, no need to repeat that. EF is not thread-safe, please stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: Thanks! My DbContext was indeed wired as Scoped in stead of Transient. Which meant a lot of static resource calls threw 500 errors cause the back-end was throwing context errors.

Comment: @AndreLuz This is the correct answer and should be accepted as such. At any rate, it earned alsami the `Unsung Hero` award.

Comment: @jcmontx "If someone else is injecting IHttpContextAccessor into the DbContext" then they are doing things **very, very** wrong and deserve whatever pain they get.

Comment: I ran into this error because I created a `List<Task<Foo>>`. The single tasks used the injected DBContext. First I tried to call await Task.WhenAll(...) and hit the error. But then I awaited them one after another in a for loop and still ran into the error. So it's important to not only await them sequentially but also to create the tasks sequentially!

Comment: Thank you, with dependency injection and asynchrous calls, the service life must be changed to transient.

Answer (score 191):

In some cases, this error occurs when calling an **async** method without the `await` keyword, which can simply be solved by adding `await` before the method call. however, the answer might not be related to the mentioned question but it can help solving a similar error.

Comment: This happened to me. Changing `First()` to `await / FirstAsync()` worked.

Comment: Upvote.  Also see https://jimlynn.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/entity-framework-error-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-completed-any-instance-members-are-not-guaranteed-to-be-thread-safe/   Jim Lynn "ENTITY FRAMEWORK ERROR: A SECOND OPERATION STARTED ON THIS CONTEXT BEFORE A PREVIOUS OPERATION COMPLETED. ANY INSTANCE MEMBERS ARE NOT GUARANTEED TO BE THREAD SAFE."

Comment: Thanks for this! This was exactly my problem...Forgot to add an await on an async mdethod.

Comment: Happened to me as well, and this comment helped as I've searched where I forgot a missing await. Once I found it, problem's solved.

Comment: with the Resharper "Errors/Warnings window" you can quickly search globally for such problems

Comment: En mi caso un metodo asincrono devolvia "void" debi agregar un tipo de respuesta

Comment: OMG! You are a legend! It took me way too long to find this

Comment: This happened to me as well, I had a series of async statements and had missed await in one of them

Comment: Thanks a lot, I published MediatR notification without await...

Comment: You are a hero, sir. I literally had ONE method I forgot to add async/await to...

Answer (score 54):

The exception means that `_context` is being used by two threads at the same time; either two threads in the same request, or by two requests.

Is your `_context` declared static maybe? It should not be.

Or are you calling `GetClients` multiple times in the same request from somewhere else in your code?

You may already be doing this, but ideally, you'd be using [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) for your `DbContext`, which means you'll be using [`AddDbContext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection) in your Startup.cs, and your controller constructor will look something like this:

```
private readonly MyDbContext _context; //not static

public MyController(MyDbContext context) {
    _context = context;
}
```

If your code is not like this, show us and maybe we can help further.

Comment: Probably it's the job I have. I managed to solve, see my answer. But I'm marking yours as the right one

Comment: @NMathur Are you using your `_context` object in other threads? Like inside a `Task.Run()` for example?

Comment: @NMathur That looks fine. Just make sure you're always using `await` with async methods. If you don't use `await`, you can unintentionally get into multi-threading.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and it turned out that **parent service was a singelton. So the context automatically became singelton too.** Even though was declared as Per Life Time Scoped in DI.

**Injecting service with different lifetimes into another**

1. Never inject Scoped & Transient services into Singleton service. (
   This effectively converts the transient or scoped service into the
   singleton. )
2. Never inject Transient services into scoped service ( This converts
   the transient service into the scoped. )

Comment: this was my issue exactly

Comment: This was my problem too. I was registering a handler class as singleton, and the DbContext as transient. I had to use ServiceProvider within the Handler class to get a transient instance from the DI container everytime the Handler is hitted

Comment: This is a very concise explanation of the most common scenario where you will experience this exception, especially if you are just starting out.

Comment: My Parent service was a scoped service, and I was injecting a transient service into it. After making it Transient too, it works fine. But I still need to learn the implications of having transient services. Thank you!

Comment: I was registering a singleton factory that returned scoped instances. Made the factory scoped as well and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 32):

- Solve my problem using this line of code in my Startup.cs file.
                Adding a transient service means that each time the service is requested, a new instance is created when you are working
  with
        Dependency injection

  ```
         services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                          options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ContextConn")),
               ServiceLifetime.Transient);
  ```

Comment: This method will cause problems in cases where the number of multi-user instant transactions is high.

Comment: It's exactly what I've stated in my post.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same error. It happened because I called a method that was constructed as `public async void ...` instead of `public async Task ...`.

Comment: It was the same for me :)

Comment: Same for me, public async void instead of Task

Answer (score 20):

I think this answer still can help some one and save many times. I solved a similar issue by changing `IQueryable` to `List`(or to array, collection...).

For example:

```
var list = _context.table1.Where(...);
```

to

```
var list = _context.table1.Where(...).ToList(); //or ToArray()...
```

Comment: IMHO, This answer does not deserve minus points, It is just poorly expressed. .ToList() indeed solves  the majority of the problems "a second operation..." due to the fact that it forces the immediate evaluation of the expression. This way there are no queueing context operations.

Comment: This was the issue in my case. I had xxx.Contains(z.prop) in a where clause of a query. xxx was supposed to be a distinct int[] array resolved from an earlier query. Unfortunately, by the time the second query hit, xxx was still an IQueryable. Adding xxx.ToArray() prior to the second query fixed my issue.

Answer (score 15):

Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same `DbContext` instance. This includes both parallel execution of `async` queries and any explicit concurrent use from multiple threads. Therefore, always `await async` calls immediately, or use separate `DbContext` instances for operations that execute in parallel.

Comment: That was the case for me. I finally found that I forgot to call await after a FirstOrDefaultAsync(..) call. It is strange that it works in Debug mode but fail in release mode.

Comment: This was the case for me. Thanks.  It works when I remove the task.When all and use await for each asyn call

Answer (score 8):

I have a background service that performs an action for each entry in a table. The problem is, that if I iterate over and modify some data all on the same instance of the DbContext this error occurs.

One solution, as mentioned in this thread is to change the DbContext's lifetime to transient by defining it like

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

but because I do changes in multiple different services and commit them at once using the `SaveChanges()` method this solution doesnt work in my case.

Because my code runs in a service, I was doing something like

```
using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
{
   var entities = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IReadService>().GetEntities();
   var writeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWriteService>();
   foreach (Entity entity in entities)
   {
       writeService.DoSomething(entity);
   } 
}
```

to be able to use the service like if it was a simple request. So to solve the issue i just split the single scope into two, one for the query and the other for the write operations like so:

```
using (var readScope = Services.CreateScope())
using (var writeScope = Services.CreateScope())
{
   var entities = readScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IReadService>().GetEntities();
   var writeService = writeScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWriteService>();
   foreach (Entity entity in entities)
   {
       writeService.DoSomething(entity);
   } 
}
```

Like that, there are effevtively two different instances of the DbContext being used.

Another possible solution would be to make sure, that the read operation has terminated before starting the iteration. That is not very pratical in my case because there could be a lot of results that would all need to be loaded into memory for the operation which I tried to avoid by using a Queryable in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem, because I was using Task.WhenAll, and DbContext instances are not thread-safe, so you can create a new DbContext for each parallel operation.

```cs
var results = await Task.WhenAll(requests.Select(async request =>
    {
        using (var dbContext = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var result = await InsertRequestIntoDatabase(request, dbContext);
            return result;
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue but the reason was none of the ones listed above. I created a task, created a scope inside the task and asked the container to obtain a service. That worked fine but then I used a second service inside the task and I forgot to also asked for it to the new scope. Because of that, the 2nd service was using a DbContext that was already disposed.

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var otherOfferService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IOfferService>();
            // everything was ok here. then I did: 
            productService.DoSomething(); // (from the main scope) and this failed because the db context associated to that service was already disposed.
            ...
        }
    }
```

I should have done this:

```
var otherProductService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IProductService>();
otherProductService.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Wouldn't the context only be exposed once everything in the using block has completed execution?

Comment: When the action is disposed, everything is disposed in that scope. If you have a task running in the background and that task is longer that the action, you will have this issue unless you create a new scope for the task, just like I did in the example. On the other hand, if your task could take long time or you want to be 100% sure that it will run, you might need to use a queue. If you are using Azure, you could use Service Bus queues.

Answer (score 4):

Adding another possible resolution to this error, in case it helps someone.

In my case the issue was using a nav property inside a query, like this:

```
var selectedOrder = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Id == id).Single();
var relatedOrders = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.User.Id == selectedOrder.User.Id).ToList();
```

The issue is using selectedOrder.User.Id in the query. If the User nav property hasn't already been loaded, EF will try to lazy load the property in the middle of trying to execute the query, which it sees as trying to start a second operation. The solution was to make a separate variable for selectedOrder.User.Id, to make sure the information needed for the query was loaded before the query started:

```
var selectedOrder = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Id == id).Single();
var userId = selectedOrder.User.Id;
var relatedOrders = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.User.Id == userId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This error might also appear if you created the migration (Add-Migration) **but forgot to actually update the database** (Update-Database).

Comment: What you have described is another potential symptom of an EF runtime that is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 3):

There is some function Async but you don't call await before it. Find and add await before calling that function will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue has been asked two years ago, but I just had this issue and the fix I used really helped.

If you are doing two queries with the same Context - you might need to remove the `AsNoTracking`. If you do use `AsNoTracking` you are creating a new data-reader for each read. Two data readers cannot read the same data.

Comment: Good pickup on the `DataReader` but there are other exceptions that can occur, this suggestion is still only a work around. You should not be trying to perform two queries at the same time against the same context, just create a new isolated context if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

put the following code in your .csproject file and correct all errors

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <WarningsAsErrors>CS4014</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

this code force you to use await for async methods

Comment: Really! I thought that I had correct calls everywhere. But thanks to this setting, I found an incorrect call

Comment: I test, and it does not work . You can try with .net8 rc2

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message. But it's not making any sense in my case. My issue is I used a "NotMapped" property by mistake. 
It probably only means an error of Linq syntax or model class in some cases. The error message seems misleading. The original meaning of this message is you can't call async on same dbcontext more than once in the same request.

```
[NotMapped]
public int PostId { get; set; }
public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
```

You can check this link for detail,
https://www.softwareblogs.com/Posts/Details/5/error-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-completed

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get that error by passing an `IQueryable` into a method that then used that IQueryable 'list' as part of a another query to the same context.

```cs
public void FirstMethod()
{
    // This is returning an IQueryable
    var stockItems = _dbContext.StockItems
        .Where(st => st.IsSomething);

    SecondMethod(stockItems);
}

public void SecondMethod(IEnumerable<Stock> stockItems)
{
    var grnTrans = _dbContext.InvoiceLines
        .Where(il => stockItems.Contains(il.StockItem))
        .ToList();
}
```

To stop that happening I used the [approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716936/1879019) and materialised that list before passing it the second method, by changing the call to `SecondMethod` to be `SecondMethod(stockItems.ToList()`

Comment: This solved the issue, but won't this slow the performance, Is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, upvote (at the least) alsami's answer.  That got me on the right path.

But for those of you doing IoC, here is a little bit of a deeper dive.

My error (same as others)

> One or more errors occurred. (A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused
>   by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more
>   information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.)

My code setup.  "Just the basics"...

```
public class MyCoolDbContext: DbContext{
    public DbSet <MySpecialObject> MySpecialObjects {        get;        set;    }
}
```

and

```
public interface IMySpecialObjectDomainData{}
```

and (note MyCoolDbContext is being injected)

```
public class MySpecialObjectEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer: IMySpecialObjectDomainData{
    public MySpecialObjectEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer(MyCoolDbContext context) {
        /* HERE IS WHERE TO SET THE BREAK POINT, HOW MANY TIMES IS THIS RUNNING??? */
        this.entityDbContext = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("MyCoolDbContext is null", (Exception)null);
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface IMySpecialObjectManager{}
```

and

```
public class MySpecialObjectManager: IMySpecialObjectManager
{
    public const string ErrorMessageIMySpecialObjectDomainDataIsNull = "IMySpecialObjectDomainData is null";
    private readonly IMySpecialObjectDomainData mySpecialObjectDomainData;

    public MySpecialObjectManager(IMySpecialObjectDomainData mySpecialObjectDomainData) {
        this.mySpecialObjectDomainData = mySpecialObjectDomainData ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMessageIMySpecialObjectDomainDataIsNull, (Exception)null);
    }
}
```

And finally , my multi threaded class, being called from a Console App(Command Line Interface app)

```
    public interface IMySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads{}
```

and

```
public class MySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads: IMySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads
{
    public const string ErrorMessageIMySpecialObjectManagerIsNull = "IMySpecialObjectManager is null";

    private readonly IMySpecialObjectManager mySpecialObjectManager;

    public MySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads(IMySpecialObjectManager mySpecialObjectManager) {
        this.mySpecialObjectManager = mySpecialObjectManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMessageIMySpecialObjectManagerIsNull, (Exception)null);
    }
}
```

and the DI buildup.  (Again, this is for a console application (command line interface)...which exhibits slight different behavior than web-apps)

```
private static IServiceProvider BuildDi(IConfiguration configuration) {
    /* this is being called early inside my command line application ("console application") */

    string defaultConnectionStringValue = string.Empty; /* get this value from configuration */

    ////setup our DI
    IServiceCollection servColl = new ServiceCollection()
        ////.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddConsole())

        /* THE BELOW TWO ARE THE ONES THAT TRIPPED ME UP.  */
        .AddTransient<IMySpecialObjectDomainData, MySpecialObjectEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer>()
    .AddTransient<IMySpecialObjectManager, MySpecialObjectManager>()

    /* so the "ServiceLifetime.Transient" below................is what you will find most commonly on the internet search results */
     # if (MY_ORACLE)
        .AddDbContext<ProvisioningDbContext>(options => options.UseOracle(defaultConnectionStringValue), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
     # endif

     # if (MY_SQL_SERVER)
        .AddDbContext<ProvisioningDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnectionStringValue), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
     # endif

    servColl.AddSingleton <IMySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads,        MySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads>();

    ServiceProvider servProv = servColl.BuildServiceProvider();

    return servProv;
}
```

The ones that surprised me were the (change to) transient for

```
        .AddTransient<IMySpecialObjectDomainData, MySpecialObjectEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer>()
    .AddTransient<IMySpecialObjectManager, MySpecialObjectManager>()
```

Note, I think because IMySpecialObjectManager was being injected into "MySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads", those injected objects needed to be Transient to complete the chain.

The point being.......it wasn't just the (My)DbContext that needed .Transient...but a bigger chunk of the DI Graph.

Debugging Tip:

This line:

```
this.entityDbContext = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("MyCoolDbContext is null", (Exception)null);
```

Put your debugger break point there.  If your MySpecialObjectThatSpawnsThreads is making N number of threads (say 10 threads for example)......and that line is only being hit once...that's your issue.  Your DbContext is crossing threads.

BONUS:

I would suggest reading this below url/article (oldie but goodie) about the differences web-apps and console-apps

https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Here is the header of the article in case the link changes.

> MANAGING DBCONTEXT THE RIGHT WAY WITH ENTITY FRAMEWORK 6: AN IN-DEPTH
>   GUIDE Mehdi El Gueddari

I hit this issue with WorkFlowCore  https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WorkflowCore" Version="3.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

sample code below.. to help future internet searchers

```
 namespace MyCompany.Proofs.WorkFlowCoreProof.BusinessLayer.Workflows.MySpecialObjectInterview.Workflows
    {
        using System;
        using MyCompany.Proofs.WorkFlowCoreProof.BusinessLayer.Workflows.MySpecialObjectInterview.Constants;
        using MyCompany.Proofs.WorkFlowCoreProof.BusinessLayer.Workflows.MySpecialObjectInterview.Glue;
        using MyCompany.Proofs.WorkFlowCoreProof.BusinessLayer.Workflows.WorkflowSteps;

        using WorkflowCore.Interface;
        using WorkflowCore.Models;

        public class MySpecialObjectInterviewDefaultWorkflow : IWorkflow<MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData>
        {
            public const string WorkFlowId = "MySpecialObjectInterviewWorkflowId";

            public const int WorkFlowVersion = 1;

            public string Id => WorkFlowId;

            public int Version => WorkFlowVersion;

            public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder<MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData> builder)
            {
                builder
                             .StartWith(context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting workflow...");
                        return ExecutionResult.Next();
                    })

                        /* bunch of other Steps here that were using IMySpecialObjectManager.. here is where my DbContext was getting cross-threaded */


                    .Then(lastContext =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        bool wroteConcreteMsg = false;
                        if (null != lastContext && null != lastContext.Workflow && null != lastContext.Workflow.Data)
                        {
                            MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData castItem = lastContext.Workflow.Data as MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData;
                            if (null != castItem)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("MySpecialObjectInterviewDefaultWorkflow complete :)  {0}   -> {1}", castItem.PropertyOne, castItem.PropertyTwo);
                                wroteConcreteMsg = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!wroteConcreteMsg)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("MySpecialObjectInterviewDefaultWorkflow complete (.Data did not cast)");
                        }

                        return ExecutionResult.Next();
                    }))

                    .OnError(WorkflowCore.Models.WorkflowErrorHandling.Retry, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
ICollection<string> workFlowGeneratedIds = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData currentMySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData = new MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData();
                    currentMySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData.MySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughDataSurrogateKey = i;

                    ////  private readonly IWorkflowHost workflowHost;
                    string wfid = await this.workflowHost.StartWorkflow(MySpecialObjectInterviewDefaultWorkflow.WorkFlowId, MySpecialObjectInterviewDefaultWorkflow.WorkFlowVersion, currentMySpecialObjectInterviewPassThroughData);
                    workFlowGeneratedIds.Add(wfid);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on `blazor 8 ssr` when I have a parent component that it contains a child component, both components get a list from database. `DbContext` inject `Scoped` by default in program.cs so I injected it as `Transient` for preventing using of the same dbcontext object in both `parent and child components` and the error resolved.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\SQLExpress2022;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")
                , ServiceLifetime.Transient); // here
```

Parent component .cs file :

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    NewsList = await appDbContext.News.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(n => n.AddDate).Take(20).ToListAsync();
}
```

Chile component .cs file :

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    IndustriesList = await appDbContext.Industries.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(i => i.Commodities).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

_Import.razor :

```
@inject AppDbContext appDbContext
```

Answer (score -5):

If your method is returning something back, you can solve this error by putting
`.Result` to the end of the job and 
`.Wait()` if it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score -6):

you can use SemaphoreSlim to block the next thread that will try to execute that EF call.

```
static SemaphoreSlim semSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

await semSlim.WaitAsync();
try
{
  // something like this here...
  // EmployeeService.GetList(); or...
  var result = await _ctx.Employees.ToListAsync();
}
finally
{
  semSlim.Release();
}
```

Comment: Please, no. It's *never* a good idea to share a context instance with multiple threads even when in serial processing.