# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed ASP NET CORE

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I encounter many trouble with this error in an ASP Net CORE mvc project and I didn't find a way to solve it :

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe
```

It append on a non async function :

```
public Employee GetEmployeeByuserID(String userID)
    {
         return _applicationDBContext.Employee.Where(e => e.UserId.Equals(userID)).First();
    }
```

I've try to make this function async but it just make the error append somewhere else.

The function is in a DAL with a dependency injection of _applicationDBContext.
The Dal is declared is declared in AddTransient in the startup.cs
I've seen some solution with an await but I counld'n find where I'm suppose to put it.

**EDIT**

If I made a breakpoint to pause the code before `return _applicationDBContext.Employee.Where(e => e.UserId.Equals(userID)).First();`
and continue, it work well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ)

Comment: I've already tried what these answers suggest, the dependency injection is a private readOnly, I maybe calling GetEmployeeById somewhere else, I will check tomorrow at work, what's the solution if I need to call it multiple time during the execution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work by creating a new DAL each request :

```
Employee emp = new EmployeeDal(new ApplicationDbContext()).GetEmployeeByuserID(appUser.Id);
```

If you have a better solution, please let me know.