# Unity Lifetime Mangers for OWIN self hosted Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, unity-container, rhino-servicebus

Im migrating a Web API from IIS to self hosting with OWIN and The UNITY lifetime managers are giving me problems. I keep getting "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed". We were using PerRequestLifetimeManager but that only works on IIS.

This is an existing system that has alot of code depending on each other so moving it to dotnet core is not an option at the moment. I have tryed using all the unity lifetime managers under microsoft.practices.unity and none of them worked. I tryed to implement my own lifetime manager and that gave me the same result. I tried to upgrade to the latest unity container and that caused problems with rhino service bus. The only code I added or changed was the code to self hos which was a few lines that to start the server and to change the api controllers to work with the self hosting

Before I change service buses I need to know if any of the new updates to unity will fix my problem or is there something else I can do to get it to work. I just need it to stop throwing a "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" error. Any thing and everything that would help is welcomed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48768221/1169180. If this doesn't work, could you post some code to replicate this issue?

Comment: That didn't work but thanks for the input. I was moved to a different project so I its someone else's problem now ;)