# Update entity error: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I update the entity, I got the error in the controller

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Code:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
   private readonly DbContext _db = new DbContext();
```

The method is

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("MyRoute")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateMyCase([Required][FromBody]MyProject body)
{
    using(var dbContextTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        _db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        var p = (from a in _db.MyProject
                 where a.Id == body.Id
                 select a).FirstOrDefault();
        p.Name = "new Name";
        p.Score = "new score";

        // ....
        var m = _db.MyProjectLink.Where(x => x.Id == p.Id);

        for(var key in m)
        {
            if(m.Any(x => x.Id != "something"))
            {
                var link = new MapProjectLink();
                link.MapId = "some id dynamic generated";
                link.Id = body.Id;
                link.Tool = key.tool;
                _db.MapProjectLink.Add(link);
            }
        }

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return OK(p);
    }
}
```

To explain the code, basically I have three tables. `_db.MyProject`, _`db.MyMap` and `_db.MapProjectLink`. The first two tables are many to many; and the third table links them together. I want to save the updated value to the two tables:  `_db.MyProject` and `_db.MapProjectLink`.

By the way I don't use dependency injection at this moment. I guess that maybe the for loop causes the problem.

The error is

> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MapProjectLink'. System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: I feel like I read something about not declaring transactions for EF because it handles that under the hood itself, I'll see If i can find something on this.

Comment: This may be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ

Comment: I read that but no big help for my specific case.

Comment: does `await _db.SaveChangesAsync();` utilize multithreading to make database writes? Could that be why its concerned about thread safe?

Comment: while `using(var dbContextTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())` should you still use the async context save?

Comment: I used to use `SaveChanges`, samething so I switch to `await _db.SaveChangesAsync()` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It's turns out I have to put everything associated with _db into `Task.Run`. Then `Wait`. Which means wait the task finish then continue to the next flow.

Comment: That's one way to fix it - see my answer for another.

Answer (score 0):

`DbContext` is not thread-safe. You should create a new context (rather then re-using the same `_db` instance for each database operation. This is a best-practice even for single-threaded processes.

Side note - that's why when you wait for each task it "works" - because you are no longer accessing your context from multiple threads.

Comment: I thought about it. But just don't know how to wrap it in code. Notice, I have `private n DbContext _db = new DbContext();` at the beginning.

Comment: Just copy that to the spots where you use the context (and wrap it in a `using` so it is disposed) : `using (DbContext db = new DbContext()) {`. Yes it's repetitive but it's the right way to use it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing to commit the transaction at the end....dbContextTransaction.Commit() after SaveChangesAsync() should do the trick.

Comment: Why? Can you add more details please?

Comment: @devendra may be onto something, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions