# C# Thread Safe CreateIdentityAsync on AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, thread-safety, asp.net-identity

If I made `more than one` API call at the same time getting error

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method in this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Exception is thrown from `var identity =  await base.currentUserService.CreateIdentity(user);` as both requests are made at the same time and CreateIdentity method of the previous request is still not finished!

How to solve the above scenario?

I want to wait for `IsValidRequest` calling in `CustomKeyAuthenticationAttribute` before the previous request finish.

Here is sample code

```
public class CustomKeyAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public IAuthService AuthService { get; set; }

    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         var isValid = await AuthService.IsValidRequest(key-from-request-header);
         if(!isValid){
             return;             
         }
         await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}

   // In side AuthService
    public async Task<bool> IsValidRequest(string key)
    {
        if (key-in-db)
        {
            var user = await base.currentUserService.GetUserById(userId-from-request-headers);

            var identity =  await base.currentUserService.CreateIdentity(user);

            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity.Result, new string[0]);
            
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

            return true;
        }
    return false
 }

  // Inside currentUserService.CreateIdentity method

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentity(CustomUser user) {
       return await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }
```

***Edit***

> stackTrace: "   at
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.ThrowingMonitor.EnsureNotEntered()    at
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)    at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)    at
> System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object
> id)    at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<GetRolesAsync>d__ac.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory`2.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see the code behind

```
var identity =  await base.currentUserService.CreateIdentity(user);
```

But my guess is that you are setting the DbContext as a shared instance between the various requests. You need to use a different context per thread.

Check [this question here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ) as I think it's the same problem.

Another similar problem [on entity framwork documentation](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/48767910/entity-framework-core--a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-completed)

Comment: Updated question with `CreateIdentity` method