# A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Cdn.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed.

```
    <MatButton OnClick="@ApplyChanges">Apply</MatButton>

    private async Task ApplyChanges()
    {
        IsDialogOpen = false;
        if (SelectedRole != null)
        {        
            Console.WriteLine("Begin IsInRoleAsync");
            if (!await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(CurrentUser, SelectedRole))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End IsInRoleAsync");
                Console.WriteLine("Begin AddToRoleAsync");
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(CurrentUser, SelectedRole);
                Console.WriteLine("End AddToRoleAsync");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End IsInRoleAsync");
            }
        }
        if (NewUsername != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin SetUserNameAsync");
            await UserManager.SetUserNameAsync(CurrentUser, NewUsername);
            Console.WriteLine("End SetUserNameAsync");
        }
        CurrentUser = null;
    }
```

It's weird because i'm not doing any operations at the same time, and this happens when i click the button twice (with time difference) and sometimes when i do it once.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ)

Comment: I have tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Does your connection string include: `;MultipleActiveResultSets=true` ?

Comment: What other actions on UserManager or other Id classes?  Where does selectedRole come form?