# A second operation started

Tags: c#

When I start my page everything loads fine I try to reload for the second time I get the following error
I run the urls from angular

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
> asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
> asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
> on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
> safe.

This is the method

```
    private readonly PuntovService  puntovService = new PuntovService(new PuntovRepository(CentralContext.Create()));
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public PuntovController()
    {
        this.mapper = WebApiApplication.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Puntos")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<PuntovDTO>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var pv = await puntovService.GetAll();
        var puntovDTO = pv.Select(x =>  mapper.Map<PuntovDTO>(x));
        var tipoComitePersona = from com in puntovDTO
                                select  new {com.PuntoV};
        return Ok(tipoComitePersona);
    }
```

in this class call the context that would be the database

```
using APICentralBL.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace APICentralBL.Data
{

    public  class CentralContext : DbContext
    {

        private static CentralContext centralContext = null;
        public CentralContext() : base("Context") 
        {
        
        }
        public DbSet<SDN> SDN {  get; set;}
        public DbSet<CALIF> CALIF { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UVT> UVT { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PUNTOV> PUNTOV { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TRANS> TRANS { get; set; }

        public static CentralContext Create()
        {
            if (centralContext == null)
                centralContext = new CentralContext();
              return centralContext;
        }
    }
}
```

It not only happens with this method, it happens when I try to call more than one

`ex.StackTrace`

```
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.ThrowingMonitor.EnsureNotEntered()
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ForEachAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source)
   en APICentralBL.Repositories.Implements.GenericRepository`1.<GetAll>d__3.MoveNext() en D:\ANTIOQUENA DEVELOPERS REPOSITORY\ANTIOQUENA DEVELOPERS\DEVELOPMENTS\API'S PROJECT\APICentral-Deploy\APICentralBL\Repositories\Implements\GenericRepository.cs: línea 33
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en APICentralBL.Services.Implements.GenericService`1.<GetAll>d__3.MoveNext() en D:\ANTIOQUENA DEVELOPERS REPOSITORY\ANTIOQUENA DEVELOPERS\DEVELOPMENTS\API'S PROJECT\APICentral-Deploy\APICentralBL\Services\Implements\GenericService.cs: línea 25
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en APICentral.Controllers.PuntovController.<GetAll>d__4.MoveNext() en D:\ANTIOQUENA DEVELOPERS REPOSITORY\ANTIOQUENA DEVELOPERS\DEVELOPMENTS\API'S PROJECT\APICentral-Deploy\APICentral\Controllers\PuntovController.cs: línea 65**
```

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Reproducible How can I reproduce all of this from here?
I don't see that there is a way

Comment: What gave you the idea to put a static `centralContext` instance inside of the DbContext class?!?!? It's weird and wrong. Just follow the Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Since your context is stored in a static field, it will be shared by all threads serving requests to your controllers concurrently. You should usually use a context per request

Comment: Thanks, can you help me a bit more specifically ?

Comment: 92 to go! Almost there