# ASP.NET CORE - An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Repository.RepositoryContext

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, dbcontext

I have been trying to fix this problem for some time now. I have an architecture where I have a repository, service, controller. Both service and repository have their managers where using DI I make all the services and repositories accessible. This is a backend for a note taking app. I already have notes, books, page elements, JTW authentication etc. and all works well. However here I started getting: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Repository.RepositoryContext'.

FULL ERROR - https://pastebin.com/gDEtq4p1

I am trying to delete a like entity, which is assigned to a post. What I do is I load the like, get the ID of the post it belongs to from it, edit the number of likes on the post (add or decrease one whether creating a like or deleting it, save the updated post to the database and then delete the like.

I am sure all asynchronous operations are implemented correctly, however I have a feeling that I am not approaching correctly the fact that I am editing one and deleting another entity during one request. I thought my context was set up for it, but it seems like no.

Here is the used code:

```
DbContext - https://pastebin.com/12v9BmjJ
RepositoryManager - https://pastebin.com/XV90nDJN
Service Manager - https://pastebin.com/bA2WkGNK
LikeService - https://pastebin.com/pykLtnn7
PostService - https://pastebin.com/pxfhqHSx
Like controller - https://pastebin.com/tmGwJwzS
```

Thank you in advance for looking at this. I know I posted a lot of code, but I am quite hopeless, tried a lot of things, nothing worked.

Comment: Please attach the code in-line - don't paste external links.

Comment: Can you describe how your DBcontext is defined? And what is the lifestyle associated with it? You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ